# Close a jQueryUI dialog after display and open a page in a new browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm opening a `jQuery` dialog when I'm clicking on the 2nd image and I'm curious how can I close the dialog after 5 seconds and force the page loading in a new window, not in the same window as is happening now. Any suggestions?

Please check the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".images").find("a").eq(1).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      open: function(e) {
        $('body').addClass('modal');
      },
      close: function(e) {
        $('body').removeClass('modal');
      }
    }).dialog("open");
    setTimeout(() => {
      /*window.location.href = $(this).prop("href");*/
      $("#dialog").dialog("close"); /*close*/
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```css
#dialog {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.modal {
  background-color: pink;
}

.modal:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src=""></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Starting the HTML -->
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="images">
    <a href="https://www.example.net">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5214132/pexels-photo-5214132.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
    <a href="https://www.example2.net">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4995558/pexels-photo-4995558.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="dialog" title="Lorem ipsum">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod amet, et minus commodi repellendus hic? Ut eos blanditiis quis provident.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `dialog` function as a `global` variable and use that `variable` to close it after `5` seconds of opening it first in [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function.

Also, to open a **tab / window** we can use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) method with `url` in it and `_blank` for a **new** window.

Working **JSFiddle** = https://jsfiddle.net/8L0jb3ef/

**Live Working Example:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".images").find("a").eq(1).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Dialogue
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      open: function(e) {
        $('body').addClass('modal');
      },
      close: function(e) {
        $('body').removeClass('modal');

      }
    }).dialog("open");

    //Close dialogue after 5
    setTimeout(() => {
      //close dialogue
      $(dialog).dialog("close")
      //redirect to new window
      window.open($(this).prop("href"), "_blank", "height=600,width=600"); //new window
    }, 5000);

  });
});
```

```css
#dialog {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.modal {
  background-color: pink;
}

.modal:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src=""></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Starting the HTML -->
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="images">
    <a href="https://www.example.net">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5214132/pexels-photo-5214132.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
      <a href="https://www.example2.net">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4995558/pexels-photo-4995558.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
      </a>
  </div>
  <div id="dialog" title="Lorem ipsum">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod amet, et minus commodi repellendus hic? Ut eos blanditiis quis provident.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JustMe I have NOT changed any code just a variable scope thats all - so you want to open the image a new window ? the image we have clicked ON ?

Comment: I need to open the link `https://www.example2.net` in another window. In the code I have, after the dialog box was closing, the link was loading in the same window. Now I want it to load in a new browser window.

Comment: @JustMe Ahh make sense. You edited the quesiton after i added the answer already for dialogue close - all good. So you want to open a => `href` - in a new window thats all - Correct just confirming ?

Comment: Yes, I want `<a href="https://www.example2.net">` to open in another browser window, before it was loading in the same window after 5 seconds of displaying the dialog box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221264/discussion-between-alwayshelping-and-justme).